# Javascript printing text in column

Tags: javascript

The main problem is that I want my new text appear in next line of the div but not on the same place or replacing the previous text.

At the moment I have the code which prints out the outcome of temperary score of player and computer.

```
    < style >
    All needed code
    < /style >

<script>
function example() {
if(player == 1) {
document.getElementById("logtxt").innerHTML = "Player rolled "+tempscore+" points"
} else if(player == 2) {
document.getElementById("logtxt").innerHTML = "Computer rolled "+tempscore+" points" }
</script>

<html>
<div class="log">
<h1>Game log<h1>
<p id="logtxt"> </p>
</div>
</html
```

Obviously there is more code, but this is the needed part for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your log strings, rather than just setting the content, you can use `+=` for this:

```
function example() {
    if(player == 1) {
        document.getElementById("logtxt").innerHTML += "Player rolled "+tempscore+" points<br />";
    } else if(player == 2) {
        document.getElementById("logtxt").innerHTML += "Computer rolled "+tempscore+" points<br />";
    }
}
```

Even better to turn it into a reusable function:

```
function log(text) {
    //log the text and start a new line
    document.getElementById("logtxt").innerHTML += text + '<br />';
}

function example() {
    if(player == 1) {
        log("Player rolled "+tempscore+" points");
    } else if(player == 2) {
        log("Computer rolled "+tempscore+" points");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another spot where it could be great to use insertAdjacentHTML..

```
document.getElementById("logtxt").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br/>Player rolled "+tempscore+" points");
```

Example explained:

Before the end of the #logtxt element (after all the current content) and you can insert the br tag to break to a new line on each entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.appendChild()` so you don't have to get and set the `.innerHTML` with `+=`, which is also an option.

```
var doc = docmument;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e;)
}
function T(t){
  return doc.createTextNode(t);
}
function C(e){
  return doc.createElement(e);
}
function example(){
  var logtxt = E('logtxt');
  if(player === 1) {
    logtxt.appendChild(T('Player rolled '+tempscore+' points'));
    logtxt.appendChild(C('br'));
  else if(player === 2){
    logtxt.appendChild(T('Computer rolled '+tempscore+' points'));
    logtxt.appendChild(C('br'));
  }
}
```